# Python: Writing to multiple CSV files at the same time

Tags: python, csv

I have one big CSV file that I read without headings. Then depending on the value of the first item in the row I need to write to a different CSV file with the same name as that value. The big file can have millions of rows.

The code below works but is a bit slow. I suspect it is because of the second `with` statement that keeps opening and closing files. The rows are not in order so all the `K93` rows are not following each other.

Is there a way to open multiple files and CSV writers and keep them open?

```py
import csv

type_list = []
counter = 0
current_type = ""
new_file_name = ""

with open("PN000047.csv", newline='') as large_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(large_file)

    for row in csv_reader:
        new_file_name = row[0] + ".csv"
        with open(new_file_name, "a", newline='') as new:
            writer = csv.writer(new)
            writer.writerow(row)
        counter += 1

print(counter)
```

I can open multple file with:

```py
from contextlib import ExitStack

...

with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [
        stack.enter_context(open(filename, "a", newline=''))
        for filename in type_list
    ]
```

After I ran through the file once and got all the file names into a list. But not sure how to open multiple CSV writers as well?

I will not know the unique file names before I read the file as it is not always the same.

Comment: something like this perhaps: create a dictionary, which maps filename to file descriptor, if the file descriptor already exists in the dictionary, use it, otherwise open the file and add it to the dictionary

Comment: @A.Najafi it's `open(new_file_name, ..)` which is expensive, not the context manager. Uku Loskit is right, pool of file handlers should have a huge effect

Comment: @UkuLoskit and at the end he/she should close all the files.

Comment: Forgot to mention: Every row with the same first value will have the same amount of columns. But for K93 there might be 5 columns and for K89 there might be 12 columns. So the big file is not a square block of data.

Comment: Have you tested reading the csv file using Pandas? @RussellTemplar

Comment: Are you on a decent OS like Linux or macOS? If so, `awk` will do that almost instantly.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary option worked well. I can now process millions of rows in seconds.

Still need a bit of cleaning and exception handling but this worked well:

```py
import csv
import time


def write_line(file_value, file_list, row):
    file_name = file_value + ".csv"
    if not any(d['item'] == file_value for d in file_list):
        file = open(file_name, "a")
        file_list.append({"item": file_value,
                          "file_name": file_name, "file": file})
    else:
        file = [d for d in file_list if d['item'] == file_value][0]["file"]

    file.write(','.join(row) + "\n")


def close_files(file_list):
    for file in file_list:
        file["file"].close()


start = time.time()

original_file = "PN000048.csv"

counter = 0
file_list = []

with open(original_file, newline='') as large_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(large_file)

    for row in csv_reader:
        write_line(row[0], file_list, row)
        counter += 1

close_files(file_list)

print("Processed lines: ", counter)
end = time.time()
duration = end - start
print(f"Duration: {duration} seconds.")
```